# Is there a pattern for wrapping a synchronous API to expose methods as Async?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asynchronous

I've been asked to use an API that makes http calls to a server behind the scenes.

Unfortunately, all the calls are synchronous.  I'd like to wrap the classes in this API so that I can make async calls, with the ability to cancel calls.

It would be a licensing violation to publish a WCF service that exposes this API.

Is there a pattern for doing this?

Comment: An API being synchronous or asynchronous should be a pure client side decision and not inherent in a service.

Comment: If the API you're calling is synchronous, then there's no way you can do anything to make the asynchronous. You can make the _appear_ to be asynchronous (by wrapping them in either a Task, or just simply using a Thread yourself), but at the end of the day, whichever thread calls that API, will be blocked waiting for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always fire off a new Task that runs in a new thread with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. If you need the competition notification on a non threadpool thread, I recommend using a `SynchronizationContext` to schedule it to a different thread.